# Alter XHR request data in chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I know that it is possible to debug XHR request in chrome debugger (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16775582/3328979) for example). But is there anyway to alter the data in the debugger before passing it to the code?

As an example assume that the XHR response is a json file `{"name":"foo"}`, I want to change this data to something like `{"name":"foo2"}` before pass it to my js code.

Comment: Set a break point and change the object

Comment: @epascarello, the code is minified. I know it is still possible but is there a clean way to do so?

Comment: click the button `{}` on the lower left in source view and make it pretty

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most easy and elegant way is to get the data in your success handler of the XHR, change the data there and use it in your js code as you need.

Comment: It a good solution but it is not a clean way. I am looking for a way to change the Response with chrome debugger.

Comment: You can also put a breakpoint with 'XHR breakpoints' dropdown in DevTools. It's in Source pane on the right, where you have 'Watch' and 'Call Stack' things. There is also XHR breakpoint. You can check 'Any XHR' and it will stop on the request. Try it, if it can help